# Sample a truncated integer power law in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, random, distribution

What function can I use in Python if I want to sample a truncated integer power law?

That is, given two parameters `a` and `m`, generate a random integer `x` in the range `[1,m)` that follows a distribution proportional to `1/x^a`.

I've been searching around `numpy.random`, but I haven't found this distribution.

Comment: Why not just do rejection sampling with the built in power law distributions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, neither NumPy nor Scipy defines this distribution for you. However, using SciPy it is easy to define your own discrete distribution function using `scipy.rv_discrete`:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def truncated_power_law(a, m):
    x = np.arange(1, m+1, dtype='float')
    pmf = 1/x**a
    pmf /= pmf.sum()
    return stats.rv_discrete(values=(range(1, m+1), pmf))

a, m = 2, 10
d = truncated_power_law(a=a, m=m)

N = 10**4
sample = d.rvs(size=N)

plt.hist(sample, bins=np.arange(m)+0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like you're integrating the pmf as if it were continuous, and taking the area between 1 and 2 to come up with p(1), between 2 and 3 for p(2), etc., is that right?  If so, for your example I think you need to emulate Spinal Tap and go to 11 to get p(10). Your `const` would be adjusted by having `(m+1)**k` in the denominator. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @pjs: I'm taking the pdf to be the *continous* function `1/x**a`. So there is no integration over intervals [1,2], [2,3], etc. However, I did integrate (by hand) to find the formulas for `const` and `_ppf`, the inverse of the `cdf`. I *think* I got it right, but I could be wrong. (I did try your suggestion, but it shifts the domain to `[1, 11]`, so if I'm understanding you correctly, that does not pass a basic sanity check.) By the way, what is Spinal Tap referring to here?

Comment: Spinal Tap was a mockumentary film about a heavy metal band. They distinguished themselves from other bands by having their amplifiers go to 11.

Comment: I'm not a pythonista so I can't directly check your results, but I've done a direct calculation for `a,m = 2,10`, and p(1) should be 0.6452579827864142. Is that what you get?

Comment: Oh dear, I'm getting `d.cdf(2) = p(1) = 0.555...`.

Comment: @pjs: I get the same result (of 0.555...) by hand, integrating `1/x**2` from `x=1` to `x=2`, and normalizing so the integral is 1 when integrated from `x=1` to `x=10`. Is that what you are doing?

Comment: No, I'm actually calculating it directly as a truncated discrete distribution.  See the answer I've posted for details.

Comment: I've revised my answer to compute a discrete pmf. Now `pmf[0] = p(1) = 0.64525798`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't use Python, so rather than risk syntax errors I'll try to describe the solution algorithmically.  This is a brute-force discrete inversion. It should translate quite easily into Python. I'm assuming 0-based indexing for the array.

Setup:

1. Generate an array `cdf` of size `m` with `cdf[0] = 1` as the first entry, `cdf[i] = cdf[i-1] + 1/(i+1)**a` for the remaining entries.
2. Scale all entries by dividing `cdf[m-1]` into each -- now they actually are CDF values.

Usage:

- Generate your random values by generating a Uniform(0,1) and
  searching through `cdf[]` until you find an entry greater than your
  uniform.  Return the index + 1 as your `x`-value.

Repeat for as many `x`-values as you want.

For instance, with `a,m = 2,10`, I calculate the probabilities directly as:

```
[0.6452579827864142, 0.16131449569660355, 0.07169533142071269, 0.04032862392415089, 0.02581031931145657, 0.017923832855178172, 0.013168530260947229, 0.010082155981037722, 0.007966147935634743, 0.006452579827864143]
```

and the CDF is:

```
[0.6452579827864142, 0.8065724784830177, 0.8782678099037304, 0.9185964338278814, 0.944406753139338, 0.9623305859945162, 0.9754991162554634, 0.985581272236501, 0.9935474201721358, 1.0]
```

When generating, if I got a Uniform outcome of 0.90 I would return `x=4` because 0.918... is the first CDF entry larger than my uniform.

If you're worried about speed you could build an alias table, but with a geometric decay the probability of early termination of a linear search through the array is quite high. With the given example, for instance, you'll terminate on the first peek almost 2/3 of the time.

Comment: Doh, it only took me two hours (and reading your answer) to realize the OP is asking for a *discrete* probability distribution...

Comment: That's why I was asking about taking range areas to yield the discrete values.

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy.random.zipf and just reject any samples greater than or equal to m